# Navigation not working in XBOX1 application

Tags: uwp, xbox, xbox-one, bbc-tal

I have created a java script based application(bbc tal framework) and build it as Universal windows platform application. The application is working fine in the windows 10 machine, but when I try to open it from XBOX1 the navigation are not at all working, Landing page is coming but it just act like an image , none of the navigation or focus is working.

I am using the below keycode for xbox gamepad control

```
        "203": "UP",
        "204": "DOWN",
        "205": "LEFT",
        "206": "RIGHT",
        "207": "INFO",

        "211": "UP",
        "212": "DOWN",
        "214": "LEFT",
        "213": "RIGHT",

        "195": "ENTER",
        "196": "BACK",
        "197": "PLAY_PAUSE",
        "198": "SEARCH",

        "202": "FAST_FWD",
        "201": "REWIND",

        "200": "PREV",
        "199": "NEXT"
```

I believe the issue is related to keycode mapping.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I have tested in my side, but I could not reproduce the issue, could you mind that share a sample simple?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT are you used bbc tal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i got the answer

```
 var boundsMode = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewBoundsMode.useCoreWindow,
        appView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.getForCurrentView();

    appView.setDesiredBoundsMode(boundsMode);
    navigator.gamepadInputEmulation = 'keyboard';
```

I have to add these lines in the index.html page, then navigation working nicely

Comment: ya its a keycode mapping issue. i also created bbc tal framework demo application for practice i faced the same issue..Now i got a idea to solve for navigation